# Ordered attachments in SES inbound email (MIME format)

Tags: amazon-web-services, mime, amazon-ses

We're using Amazon SES to receive emails from a certain sub-domain. We configured it to pass the emails to an Amazon S3 Bucket.

We noticed that the email in S3 (MIME) does not show the list of attachments in the same order that they were attached when the email was being composed.

Is there a way to order the attachments in the email file in the same order that they were attached?